# Ideas for experiments on the Beamline for Schools at CERN?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, education

I'm thinking of participating in CERN's Beamline for schools competition. To those who do not know, they offer a batch from a school to conduct their own experiment on a small scale particle accelerator.

Some ideas from you guys would really be helpful to get me started on thinking of some experiment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a discussion not a question. [You could tray asking in the chat room though](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) if you can raise your reputation score to above 20.